# Webhooks for Pages

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

My app doesn't have the 'pages_manage_metadata' permission yet.
So I use `Graph API Explorer` to Subscribe my app Webhook for a Facebook Page.

*[GET] me/subscribed_apps
return

```
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Business",
      "link": "{https://}",
      "name": "{App Name}",
      "id": "{App Id}",
      "subscribed_fields": [
        "messages",
        "feed",
        "mention"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I comment on a page's post, I just get notified with data returned: {}.
The same goes for when I use the 'Feed Test' in the 'Webhooks / Page' menu of the App.
How can I get this data?

Comment: Hi, just write controller for event handling and place same url in webhook your odoo will start getting data.

Comment: yes, but returned data is an empty dictionary. Does this have something to do with whether I use Graph API Explorer or not. Because my app doesn't have the 'pages_manage_metadata' permission yet